# Why is dreaming of getting married considered a disturbance?

Tags: marriage, death, mysticism-kabbalah, fast-days, dream

I know that this is a pretty mystical question, but is anyone able to provide an explanation as to why the Shulchan Aruch (OH 288:5) says that seeing oneself get married in a dream is considered bad enough that they should have a taanis chalom, whereas dreaming of dying is considered a positive?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya Abraham! Thanks for sharing the question. Posts here are almost always improved with sources for multiple reasons. One of them is that it facilitates users finding the answer. In this case, for example, a citation to the passage in ShA would be a great help in finding an explanation of it. Consider learning more about the site from this short useful [Beginners' Guide](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/8775). Hopefully you'll choose to stick around...

Comment: I took the liberty of editing in the source for the Shulhan Arukh. Feel free to further [edit](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/82699/edit).

Comment: FWIW besides for those who reject the significance of dreams in general, some reject the premise of the question, and state specifically that these are _good_ omens. Cf. R. Yaakov Hagiz cited in Yehave Daat (4:24).

Comment: Where did you see the dream about death being a good omen?